# logitech dual shock Python support

Tags: gamepad

Does anyone know how to use "dual vibration feedback makes your games more realistic and immersive." on this logitech gamepad

I know about pygame however I don't think it gives feedback.

http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-gamepad-f710

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is on Windows you'll probably want to use [DirectInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) either via a Python wrapper if you can find / write one, or by using another programming language like C++ or C#.

A quick search suggests pyglet has at least some DirectInput support, but I don't know if that includes force feedback.